# Where does the %rax register come from in this assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have the following x86_64 assembly code, and I am supposed to translate it into C code.

```
trace:
tp in %rdi
    movl $0, %eax
    testq %rdi, %rdi
    je  .L3
.L5:
    movq (%rdi), %rax
    movq 16(%rdi), %rdi
    testq %rdi, %rdi
    jne    .L5
.L3:
    rep
    ret
```

My question is, where does the %rax come from? Is it just another register in which I'm storing tp after the movq instruction? And if so, why would doing that benefit me, what's wrong with leaving it in %rdi? Thanks

Comment: `movq (%rdi), %rax` does not move the contents of `%rdi` into `%rax`, it moves the contents of *memory* at the address pointed to by `%rdi` into `%rax`. The code traverses a linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`movl $0, %eax` zero-extends to set the 64-bit register `%rax <- 0`, so if `(%rdi == 0)`, this will be the return value in a typical [ELF/SysV ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi-0.99.pdf). That includes Linux / BSD and OS X. Otherwise, the `%rax` return value will be a result of the loop.